# SAPUI5 app with OData authentication + restriction by authorizations

Tags: authentication, odata, sapui5

I have some problems to understand the Login with a SAPUI5 App connected with the OData to a SAP-Server.

First of all, the idea is like a time recognition where i login with the user id or username and password. than i check if it is in the SAP backend system and if it is. i want to show only the records for the staff number.

I am doing it with filters? or there are some other ways?

It should be a basic authentication, when I open the app there is a popup where I need to enter my sap-system username and password, but how I can make this as a login page and how can I get the parameters (every username has a staff number)?

Comment: Where is the app going to be hosted?

Comment: on our sap-server, or what do you mean? its connected with a cloud connector

Comment: SAP-Server? Is the App running on an On-premise NW Frontend gateway system or on SAP Cloud platform?

Comment: ah sorry, missunderstaning.. it should run later on the sap cloud platform. Now it runs or i run it from the webide and dont put it on the cloud platform

Comment: Your backend needs to map a user name to a staff number. This should not be done in the frontend. You can create a custom logon page like described in this blog post: https://blogs.sap.com/2007/04/06/bsphowto-customizing-the-design-of-system-logon-page-in-netweaver-04/

Comment: its already mapped but how i do it in the frontend? its a filter? or how you get the staff number? I mean i access on the full Set for example TIMESet and there all the entrys from all the staff right? So it is like stuffnumber filtering or how it works than?

Comment: You should rather filter in the SAP backend according to sy-uname instead of reading ALL TimeSets ... this will end up in performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

first of all I think you need to understand some basic concepts/architecture settings.

There are two possibilities deploying SAPUI5 apps:

- hosted on your SAP NW GW onPremise (no matter if central hub or not)
- hosted on SAP Cloud Plattform

Case A: deploying on SAP NW GW onPremise

- in this case you could override the ICF classes to achieve custom login and logout explained here: https://blogs.sap.com/2016/11/25/sapui5-application-with-custom-login-and-logout-option/ | I will not explain this is further depth

Case B: hosting a SAPUI5 App on SAP Cloud Platform

- in this case your need to understand the architecture to determine what you want
- If your SAP Cloud Platform hosts the SAPUI5 application your can read data from an SAP Backend using SAP Cloud Platform Destination Services (which means a destination, using the SAP Cloud Connector to connect to your SAP System)

In your case: *First of all, the idea is like a time recognition where i login with the user id or username and password.. than i check if it is in the sapbackend system and if it is.. i want to show ONLY the records for the staffnumber..*
--> I would recommend the following: If the app is hosted on SAP CP you need an S-User to access it or a respective single sign on mechanism to replace s-user. You will not be able to replace the login from Cloud Platform with anything individual not breaking security terms. Then you need a SAP NW GW OData Service in your SAP Backend. You further need SAP Cloud Connector paired with your SAP System and with your SAP CP instance. Having both things in place requires creating a destination pointing to your OData Service. If you got these things in place you could easily select the destination when creating an SAPUI5 Application via templates.

Help Links:

- SSO for SAP CP:
- https://blogs.sap.com/2017/04/13/configure-saml-sso-for-sap-cloud-platform-using-an-external-identity-provider/
- Destinations in SAP CP:
- https://www.sap.com/developer/tutorials/hcp-create-destination.html
- https://blogs.sap.com/2018/03/09/understanding-destination-types-available-in-sap-cloud-platform-mobile-service/
- https://www.sap.com/developer/tutorials/teched-2016-3.html
- Cloud Connector Setup:
- https://www.sap.com/developer/tutorials/hcp-cloud-connector-setup.html
- SAP NW GW OData Service
- https://blogs.sap.com/2016/05/31/odata-service-development-with-sap-gateway-code-based-service-development/

Have fun

Comment: ps: if your requirement is really to implement a custom login, which I doubt, then you should follow the link from Marc https://blogs.sap.com/2007/04/06/bsphowto-customizing-the-design-of-system-logon-page-in-netweaver-04/. I do not believe that you want a second login page for a user who has to use the app (from SAP CP and your individual).